# How to run scripts every 5 seconds?

Tags: scripts, cron

I have a script that needs to be run every five seconds. I know that `cron` can do tasks by the minute, but is there a way to run something every second?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you sure cron is the right solution?

Comment: I know cron isn't the right solution. I was saying it wasn't in the question. Please read.  I am trying to make a script run every 5 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, guess I got the question slightly wrong. Yet, still wondering if you are trying to solve the right problem.

Comment: For people coming here looking how to run something every 5 seconds. I strongly recommend instead you look at learning how to program realtime with tools like socket.io as an example.

Comment: Have you discovered the bash sleep command?  `sleep 5` pauses (perhaps within a loop) for 5 seconds)...?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute. What you **could** do is write a shell script with an infinite loop that runs your task, and then sleeps for 5 seconds. That way your task would be run more or less every 5 seconds, depending on how long the task itself takes.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  # Do something
  sleep 5;
done
```

You can create a `my-task.sh` file with the contents above and run it with `sh my-task.sh`. Optionally you can configure it with `supervisor` as a service so that it would start when the system boots, etc.

It really does sound like you're doing something that you probably shouldn't be doing though. This feels *wrong*.

Comment: One can need a a cron running every 5 or even less seconds to be used in PHP based scrapers.

Comment: Really feels wrong. If you include it in a cron job then you will have overlapping jobs every minute. After an hour 60 jobs will be starting every 5 seconds. If you do not include in a cron job, well, you may not be able to know how to stop it, or even to know it exists.

Answer (score 50):

You could have a `cron` job kick-off a script every minute that starts 12 backgrounded processes thusly:

```
* * * * * ~/dostuff.sh
```

`dostuff.sh`:

```
(sleep 5 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 10 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 15 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 20 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 25 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 30 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 35 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 40 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 45 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 50 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 55 && /path/to/task) &
(sleep 60 && /path/to/task) &
```

---

My question, though, is ***What on EARTH*** could you be doing that needs to run every 5 seconds?

Comment: Well, this came in handy to me when I made a script that repeatedly checks the `/media` directory for a drive I plug in to usb for automatic backups...

Comment: `What on EARTH` - statistics, garbage collection, file sync, online status, you name it.

Comment: Referencing external API for near-realtime data. Running request every 5 sec is MUCH better than doing it on every pageview.

Comment: What if crontab execute the dostuff.sh file twice? For example at 55th second, the script is executed but didn't finished yet, but the cron calls the script again, what'll happen?

Comment: Recording usage into a file for a load balancer to review and balance based on.

Comment: Sending CPU Load and Network Usage data back to InfluxDB, using a homegrown monitoring solution.

Comment: THIS IS BAD! It potentially runs the script *more than once at a time* (if it happens to take longer than 5 seconds) which could lead to a race condition in any (even temporary) files accessed. DO NOT DO THIS if doing the same thing twice at the same time could cause a problem! (And that **usually** will!)

Comment: Running script more than once at a time may not be bad in some cases. Depends on what it's doing.

Answer (score 29):

Just use a loop:

```
while true ; do ./your-script & sleep 5; done
```

This will start your-script as a background job, sleep for 5 seconds, then loop again.
You can use Ctrl-C to abort it, or use any other condition instead of `true`, e.g. `! test -f /tmp/stop-my-script` to only loop while the file `/tmp/stop-my-script` does not exist.

Comment: If I include the ampersand, it says `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'`, so I took it out. I have bash 4.3.11. My command runs quickly so it's ok if it runs in the foreground.

Comment: @TylerCollier If you did need `./your-script` to run in the background (during the 5-second sleep), you could keep `&` but drop the `;`. As `&` serves the purpose of separating the commands, it's unnecessary (and apparently not allowed) to have `;` after it on the same line. Another way is to write the loop in multiple lines (with a line break after `&` and, optionally, line breaks after `do` and before `done` as well). Since the `;` after `&` appears to be a typo, I've removed it. blueyed: Please feel free to put the `;` back if you really want it; if so, I suggest also adding an explanation.

Comment: @EliahKagan FWIW, it works on Zsh (no syntax error), but it is not really necessary.  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 12):

You could use the GNU package **mcron**, a "Vixie cron" alternative.

http://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/mcron.html#Top

*"Can easily allow for finer time-points to be specified, i.e. seconds. In principle   this could be extended to microseconds, but this is not implemented."*

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Please post this as an answer to my question here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/922216/is-there-a-more-granular-cron-like-scheduler-instead-of-just-by-the-minute-but so I can accept your answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470965/how-can-you-watch-gnuplot-realtime-data-plots-as-a-live-graph-with-automatic-up/44471008#44471008

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/832072/can-i-use-cron-to-chime-at-top-of-hour-like-a-grandfather-clock?rq=1

Comment: `mcron` requires `sendmail` to be installed and activated by default. how to disable it?

Answer (score 7):

You could use a SystemD timer unit, which will trigger a service - that you'd set up to do what you want - every 5 seconds.

Suppose your service unit is called `mystuff.service` and is installed in `/etc/systemd/system` (check out [SystemD user services](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) if you want to replace a user's crontab), then you can write a timer unit to run the service at boot time and then every 5 seconds, like this:

`/etc/systemd/system/mystuff.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=my stuff's schedule
[Timer]
OnBootSec=5
OnUnitActiveSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Then reload the systemd configuration, enable the timer unit and start it.

Comment: It's the best solution, the only downside is that cron is a lot easier to overview and configure. SystemD is a pain and it starts with it's directory structure. 
Still the best for a 5 second interval

Comment: Wouldn't the above snippet go in /etc/systemd/system/mystuff.timer instead of mystuff.service?

Comment: @Brooks: yes, my bad - bad copy & paste on my side. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks...glad to know I'm not crazy while I'm learning systemd :)

Comment: I love this approach

Answer (score 2):

Minimum configuration in cron is minutes, you can't set it for 5 seconds. You could use Quartz which does allow seconds. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: It seems Quartz is not open source. Is this correct?

Comment: It has an open source version. It doesn't have a page but just go to the download page. You don't have to fill out the form just click take me to the download.

Comment: seems to be open source as of at least 2018. https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz

Answer (score 2):

Use cacti to monitor router and switch,but Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute,so
 if one port/device down,there is no warning until two minutes past.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

I've done this sort of thing very successfully (and the end result rans weeks at a time, till the machine is rebooted).  As for what I was doing right now, updating information and putting it into cache - updating every 10 seconds.

```
#!/bin/sh

SLEEP=5

# do stuff
sleep $SLEEP

# do stuff
sleep $SLEEP

# do stuff
sleep $SLEEP

# do stuff
sleep $SLEEP

# echo and restart...
exec $0
```

The 'exec $0' restarts the script, but replacing the running script.  It can be initially started with a crontab '@reboot' line.

Comment: Why not use a `while` loop instead of repeatedly restarting the script?