# Is there a more granular cron-like scheduler? Instead of just by the minute, but at a certain second?

Tags: sound, schedule

I would like to use a small linux system to do ID-insertions for a small internet-fed radio station.  The program allows for 20 seconds of just a musical "bed" around the top of each hour.  But it is complicated because there are three kinds of hour-wheel formats.

For it to work it would need to be able to trigger a playback sound at very specific times, like at 20 seconds past the top of the hour for certain hours, 20 seconds before the hour on other hours, and right at the top of the hour for yet other hours.

I know I can write a Python program to do this, and it might be advantageous to just do it myself.

But I wonder if some kind of a scheduler program like this might already exist?

--EDIT - OK, I see the beginnings of an answer in the comments.   Turns out that @muru pointed me to mcron which is precisely what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: mcron, maybe? https://askubuntu.com/a/465340/158442

Comment: No, not a duplicate.  I need precision timing on an hourly basis with three differrent types over the 24 hours in a day.  BUT YES about mcron.  If you post that as an answer I will accept it.  That is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470965/how-can-you-watch-gnuplot-realtime-data-plots-as-a-live-graph-with-automatic-up/44471008#44471008