# How can I run a systemd service periodically?

Tags: scripts, systemd, services

```
[Unit]
Description=captive portal automation

[Service]
Type=simple

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/do.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
```

The above is the content of a systemd service called `caportal.service` running on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I need to repeat the service for every 30 minutes. How can i do that ?

/home/pi/do.py

```
import requests,json
import netifaces as ni
import commands as cm


gateway=ni.gateways()['default'][ni.AF_INET][0]

IPaddr=ni.ifaddresses('wlan0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
mac=ni.ifaddresses('wlan0')[ni.AF_LINK][0]['addr'].upper().replace(':','-')
ssid=cm.getoutput('iwgetid -r')
Home="http://"+gateway+":8010/"

URL=Home+"login.html"
print URL
d={}
d['IdSession']=mac
d['Language']='English'
d['refrescar']='0'
d['ip']=IPaddr
d['mac']=mac
d['DSP']=Home
d['AC']='1'
d['userlog']='vishnu'
d['userpass']='12345'
d['read']='checkbox'
d['Login']='+++Go+++'

try:
    if ssid=='machCochin':
        r=requests.post(URL,data=d)
        print r.status_code
        #raise ValueError("ERROR simulated")
    else:
        print "network is not machCochin"
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Comment: Have you considered using cron for it? That's probably simpler. Or make a script that does it, sleeps for 30 minutes, and repeats it? Then you could run the script as a service...

Answer (score 5):

*systemd* provides an ananalog of the cron jobs. They are called *timer*.

You need to create both a `.service` file to run your script and a `.timer` file with matching filename to schedule it.

Something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=run my script

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00/5:05
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

To run every 5 minutes for example. I let you dig the man page or you search engine to look the `OnCalendar` directive or others too.

You can even run as a user by placing both files in `~/.config/systemd/user/` or as root in `/etc/systemd/system`

You need activate the timer to get it running after you reboot

```
sudo systemctl enable myservice.timer
```

Add `--user` to the command above  (and without sudo) if you run as a user from `./config`

Then, run it with

```
sudo systemctl start myservice.timer
```

or

```
systemctl --user start myservice.timer
```

Comment: How would use configure this to persist through a reboot?  I've followed the docs, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: FTR: I used a `OnUnitActiveSec` field instead as it allow much easier syntax like `30m` or `1day`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@martin-w to answer your question, you could add OnBoot directive under the Timer section. Something like

```
[Unit]
Description=run my script

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00/5:05
OnBootSec=5
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

You can check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097412/1309493) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for offering your support. Please take the [tour] to increase your awareness of how this community operates.  One minor concern is that all answers must attempt to resolve the issue described in the question -- not resolve comments made under a post.  I don't know enough about this subject matter to determine if your answer resolves the question, but it must.  A follow up question from the OP should either be added to the question body or asked as a new question so that this page doesn't descend into a forum thread / discussion.